# php simple livestream not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, server, video-streaming

I want to make a very simple version of Twitch (client side and server side, no accounts, only two users) in the fileupload.php the first user should choose a video and in the streamer.php the second user watch the video before the video is 100% uploaded.

In my program it work only if the video is 100% uploaded, but I want if 1% is uploaded, the other person can watch the 1% of the video.

Preferable with PHP and without a library.
Sorry for my bad English I am just learning.

Thanks alot for your answers!

fileupload.html (JS, uploadFile()):

```
var file = document.getElementById("file1").files[0];   
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file1", file);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
ajax.send(formdata);
```

fileupload.html (html)

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input class="fileUpload" type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
<input id="uploadBtn" type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
</form>
```

file_upload_parser.php:

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"];

if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "uploads/$fileName")){
    echo "complete";
}
?>
```

VideoStream.php: https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293

streamer.php

```
<?php
    $path = $_GET['path'];
    include "VideoStream.php";
    $stream = new VideoStream($path); 
    $stream->start();exit;
?>

<video controls preload="auto" src="<?php echo $path ?>" width="100%"></video>
```

Comment: That isnt gonna work like that. Simply uploading a video will not do it in a format so that it can be streamed. Also php is server side. So as soon as someone load the page it loads the video in its current state (not finished yet) It wont automaticly retrieve a new version when available. You would need a lot of knowledge to write this on your own. why cant you use libs etc for this?

Comment: @Merijndk Thanks for your answer. I don't want to use libs, because I can then expand it better. Later I also want to create user and other things. :/